# Adding javascript to admin view and user view

Tags: 8, javascript

I have a form with a text plain long description field. Added Javascript to limit the amount of characters allowed in the field.

```
(function($){
    $("#edit-field-busines-0-value").attr('maxlength','500');
})(jQuery);
```

It works for the Authenticated users view, but not for the Admin users view? How can I have this work on the Admin view also?

Comment: Can you also post your code here? how did you add your javascript in form?

Comment: edited the question with the simple script to limit the characters.

Comment: @iamroald not sure i follow you? js/custom.js file is added to the libraries.yml as a global styling sheet

Comment: Which libraries.yml? The one in your theme? If so, make sure you're using that theme for admin

Comment: @Clive thats what it was....

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this library is being pulled in by your public theme, but not by your admin theme? Authenticated users probably are maybe not seeing the edit from in the context of your admin theme, like admins are. If so, add the library to your admin theme too (you can create a sub-theme of Seven and add it there).